# move_uploaded_file retorna apenas FALSE

Tags: php, imagem, post, file-upload

Estou com um problema que não consegui identificar, `move_uploaded_file` retorna apenas `FALSE` independentemente do que eu passe nas parâmetros. Segue código:

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="img" />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1024000" /> 
</form>
```

```
$way = BASE_URL."media/";
$name = basename($_FILES['img']['name']);
$uploadfile = $way.$name;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Estou aqui!";
} else {
    echo "Não foi dessa vez.";
}
```

---

Dando um `print_r` em `$_FILES['img']` retorna esta array

```
Array
(
    [name] => RgtoGIN.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpfLzDGR
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 147270
)
```

Comment: Anorak, as soluções devem estar nas respostas, não na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já checou o que tem no valor `error` a variável `$_FILES['img']` ?

O valor `'error'` retorna `0` quando não existe erro no upload. O PHP disponibiliza a constante chamada `UPLOAD_ERR_OK` para você checar se o upload ocorreu sem erro.

Exemplo:

```
 if ($_FILES['img']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 
     exit('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar fazer o upload');
 }
```

Se qualquer outro valor for retornado, você pode checar através das constantes abaixo:

```
UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE
UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL
UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR
UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE
UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION
```

Essa é a primeira coisa ser feita quando um upload falha.

Na Documentação do [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.errors.php) fala sobre isso.

Comment: Já tinha feito o teste para ver oque me retornava, e o valor retornado no var_dump($_FILES['img']['error']) é 0, retornando isso o move_uploaded_file deveria funcionar normalmente correto? Mas ele retorna FALSE.

Comment: O que é retornado em `$_FILES['img']['tmp_name']`?

Comment: Dando um print_r em $_FILES['img'] retorna essa array:
Array
(
    [name] => RgtoGIN.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpfLzDGR
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 147270
)

Comment: Eu estou começando a desconfiar que você está bebendo barro no caminho do arquivo. Tenta fazer isso que vou fazer, sem upload, pra ver se retornar algum erro: `file_put_contents(BASE_URL."media/xxx.txt", 'hello')`. Se o arquivo aparecer na pasta, tudo bem. Se não, me informe.

Comment: Consegui encontrar uma resposta muito útil na internet, que resolveu meu problema, o grande problema é que ao passar o caminho para onde o arquivo será direcionado não pode haver (http://...) OU (https://...), o correto é passar apenas no estilo Unix (./diretório/arquivo). Fazendo desta forma o arquivo é passado corretamente e salvo sem problemas. Obrigado pela ajuda.